# What's a clean way to handle java SQL exceptions and retries?

Tags: sql, jdbc

I'm stuck with this requirement that I need to try X times before calling it quits.

I personally prefer to fail and notify immediately but hey...

So...

```
for retries
    try
        connect
        exececute sql
        process sql
        commit
        if all is good break loop
    catch
        rollback
```

With what exceptions should you retry vs not retry? On a connection drop I figure yes. But if everything is an SQLException how do you differentiate when you should and not? Or should I just retry period?

Comment: Since you can't rollback without a connection, I suggest your `connect` call is in the wrong place. :-)

Comment: Should only be sqlexceptions, and even that's iffy, aside from time outs due to poor network or db locking, there's no reason it should work second time through, and silent retry is a crap fix for that sort of issue.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Should I bother check the type of DB error or just retry period.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A null check or connection closed check before calling rollback right?

Comment: @user432024: I'd probably move it out of the try and handle it in a different try/catch/finally block.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: It would have been really nice if you can differentiate between a network error and the rest with out having to figure out status codes. I figure if the connection failed you can retry for the sake of retrying. As for any other exception you can't really do anything about it. If you get NULL column or invalid syntax, wrong username etc.. Whats the point...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thats worst because now you have to do retry loop catch on 2 separate parts even more mess. It think a simple NULL check and connection open is enough no? Anyways I'm not to worried about commit/rollback more in general how to write nice clean reusable code. Unless i really have to split the two.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: This intersting, in JDBC 4.0 they added a bunch of new SQLExceptions, which helps
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbc4exception.html

Comment: @user432024: If you're going to connect for each statement (I sure hope that's not really a connect, but a request to a pool or something), then yes, a `null` check would be okay.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder of course! Anyways JDBC 4.0 has some nice new SQL exceptions and JAVA SE 7 Closeable. To bad we aren't there yet lol

Comment: It's always been a bit iffy, you can still get OLE Exceptions from SQL Server with .net. Have to partse teh error text to see what it is, very irritating. Our policy is if an exception is raised, blow chunks , log, die, and then contact Tony and his colleagues with the error message. Very very rare, we handle an exception as the normal course of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a count variable. It doesn't make sense to loop through there for lifelong. Have certain tries count. If all is good (or) reached count, break loop. This is what I prefer.